# how to get data from another sheet in excel using IF function

Tags: excel, if-statement, calculated-columns

I want to develop an IF function using the new RecommendedExchange Rate Type value.

From the DataInput worksheet I'll calculate the Cost Price (AU) (in the Cost Price (AU) column) using the following criteria:

If the Exchange Rate Type is NL then the Cost Price (AU) is calculated by multiplying the Cost Price (NL) by the Exchange Rate (NL to AU) cell on the DataInput worksheet

Comment: While what you are saying is very nice, its still missing information.  It would be really helpful if you provided an example data table of your DataInput worksheet.  Currently we have no clue where or how the information for the Exchange rate is held on that sheet.  Is there just one exchange rate, or are there multiple exchange rates depending on the currency.  We dont need your entire spreadsheet, but enough of an example are that we can work with.

Answer (score 2):

in order to reference a cell on another sheet, instead of using:

```
=A1
```

you need to include the sheet name in front of it.  So if we want to reference A1 on another sheet we use:

```
='another sheet'!A1
```

So in order to build your IF statement, you would build it like another other if statement, you would just need to include the sheet name with the cell reference for those cells located on other worksheets.

As an example in order to pull the value from B3 on sheet3 when the value of the current sheet cell `M42` is TTT, but to pull the valus from A1 on the BRAINS sheet it would look something like:

```
=IF(M42="TTT",'sheet3'!B3,'BRAINS'!A1)
```

The IF function is made up of three parts:

- The logical check, conditional check, what ever you want to call it that resolves to either TRUE or FALSE
- The TRUE result action
- The FALSE result action

Each to the parts is separate by a comma and looks like this in the general sense:

```
IF(CONDITION CHECK, TRUE action, FALSE action)
```

Now if you do not put the FALSE action in, and the condition check returns false, then the result of your IF function will display FALSE.

Comment: but how the calculation part goes?

Comment: you calculation part will either go in the true part of the if statement of the false part of the if statement depending what you need done based on the logical check part of the IF statement.